# Melt Data and fill new column with desired data

Tags: r

Hello coding community

I have a two part question that is **1/2** answered

1. transpose, aka melt data frame, to my liking  - **done**
2. add rows of data based on results found in "removed" column, a column created in the transposing step - **stuck here**

   ```
   df<- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/NEPcUG01",header=T, sep="\t")
   df_transformed<-tidyr::gather(df, day, removed, -(1:2), na.rm = TRUE) # melted data
   ```

In my example here (df), I have an experiment ran over 8 days. On certain days, I remove data points, and I am only interested in these days (hence why I added na.rm = TRUE in the transposing process).  I sometimes remove 1 data point, or 4 (but this could be any number really)

I would like the removed data points to be called "individuals", and for them to be counted in chronological order.  Therefore, I first need to add a column called "individuals"

```
    df_transformed$individual <- ""
```

I would like to fill in the "individual" column based on the results in the "removed" column.

example:  cage 2 had only 1 data point removed, and it was on day_8.  I would therefore like to add, in the "individual" column, a 1. Cage 4, on the other hand, had data points removed on day_5 (1 data point) and day_7 (3 data points), for a total of 4 data points , aka , 4 "individuals".  Therefore, Cage 4, when starting with day_5, I would like to add a 1 in the "individuals" column, and for day 7, create 3 total rows of data, and continue my "individual count" with 2,3,4.  IF day_8 had 3 more data points removed, the individual count would continue with 5,6,7.

My desired result for my example data set today would be this:

```
    desired_results <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/r7QrC0y3", header=T, sep="\t") # 68 total rows of data
```

Interesting piece of information:  The total number of rows in my final data set should equal the sum of all removed data points:

```
    sum(df_transformed$removed) # 68
```

Thank you StackOverflow community.  Looking forward to seeing the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` to create a sequence from 1 to each `individual` grouped by `cage` and `day`. We then `fill` the NA values in columns `experiment` and `removed`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_transformed %>%
  mutate(individual = removed) %>%
  group_by(cage, day) %>%
  complete(individual = seq_len(individual)) %>%
  fill(experiment, removed, .direction = "up")

#   cage   day individual   experiment removed
#1     2 day_8          1        sugar       1
#2     3 day_5          1        sugar       1
#3     4 day_5          1        sugar       3
#4     4 day_5          2        sugar       3
#5     4 day_5          3        sugar       3
#6     4 day_7          1        sugar       1
#7     7 day_7          1        sugar       1
#8     7 day_8          1        sugar       1
#9     8 day_5          1        sugar       2
#10    8 day_5          2        sugar       2
# … with 58 more rows
```

---

To update `individual` only based on `cage` we can do

```
df_transformed %>%
  mutate(individual = removed) %>%
  group_by(cage, day) %>%
  complete(individual = seq_len(individual)) %>%
  group_by(cage) %>%
  mutate(individual = row_number()) %>%
  fill(experiment, removed, .direction = "up")
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak

What an advancement! This is **almost** perfect. :) Would there be a way to have the "individual" column be filled in consecutive order with respect to cage and day?  Your code does this, however if the day changes, the numbers start again at 1.  For example:

Look at cage 4 in your results.  Day 5 = 3 data points removed, and Day 7 = 1 data point removed.  Your individual count starts on day 5 with 1,2,3 (great!), but for day 7, still cage 4, it restarts with an individual count of 1, however because it's still the same cage, I would like it to continue and be 4.

Comment: @Andy It happens because the data is already grouped by `cage` and `day`. I have updated the answer which should give you what you need.

Comment: Hello again @Ronak Shah.  I double checked, and it's **exactly** what I need. 

I'm struggling to understand how your code works. I'm not familiar with all the commands, such as mutate(), my new task is now to translate this, line by line, so I get what you did :) .  Many thanks as always!!

Comment: yes, going through each one of them line by line would help you to understand what each function does. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following bit of code does what you need:

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/NEPcUG01",header=T, sep="\t") %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with("day_"), names_to = "day", values_to = "removed") %>%
    # drop_na() %>%
    group_by(cage) %>%
    summarize(individual = sum(removed, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I have used the pipe operator (`%>%`), which enables cleaner syntax. I have also used the newer `pivot_longer` function instead of gather. Then, grouping by cage and later summing over the individual column with `summarize` you get how many individuals were removed per cage.

I checked the sum of all the individuals and it seems to work:

```r
read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/NEPcUG01",header=T, sep="\t") %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with("day_"), names_to = "day", values_to = "removed") %>%
    # drop_na() %>%
    group_by(cage) %>%
    summarize(individual = sum(removed, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    pull(individual) %>%
    sum()

#> [1] 68
```

The result is slightly different to your desired result. I am not 100% your desired result is actually correct... From your question, I understand that cage 4 should have 4 individuals, but in your `desired_result` it appears 4 times with values 1, 2, 3 and 4. The code I sent you generates a data frame where each appears in a single row.

Comment: Thanks @albgarre!

I ran your code, and it does melt the data according to my likings, but, your code sums the total # of data points removed into 1 line per cage. I would like them to each have their own line.  Lets continue with cage 4 as you suggested:

We agree cage 4 has 4 total data points (3 from day5, 1 from day7).  I would like my final generated list to start with the earliest day a point was removed, and to continue on consecutively, where each individual has it's own row.  This is why, in my desired results dataframe, cage 4 appears 4 total times.